# NiFi: creating FieldValue for given value

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to create a Record from raw values. I do this:

```
List<RecordField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
RecordField field1= new RecordField("field1", RecordFieldType.STRING.getDataType());
fields.add(field1);
....
....
SimpleRecordSchema schema = new SimpleRecordSchema(fields);
final Record mapRecord = new MapRecord(schema, new HashMap<>());
final List<FieldValue> selectedFields = new ArrayList<>();
// TODO how to create FieldValue instances from raw values
for (final FieldValue selectedField : selectedFields) {
    mapRecord.setValue(selectedField.getField(), selectedField.getValue());
}
```

I am not sure how to create FieldValue from a raw value. Say I have value "test", and I have to create a FieldValue for it.

How do we do it?